# laravel 4 - detectEnvironment dosen't work

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I am trying to set up 2 environment to my laravel 4 project and i just can't id the project environment.

I see in the source code that detectEnvironment in the start.php uses is:

```
    $args = isset($_SERVER['argv']) ? $_SERVER['argv'] : null;
```

but when i dd (print) the  $_SERVER['argv'] its empty (return null on live server and on my local machine).

do i need to set it up someone?

- keep in mind my live server is shared host and i have limited access to config.
- i did open dir in /config/ with database.php and set up everything in start.php:

.

```
$env = $app->detectEnvironment(array(

    'local' => array('*local*'),

    'live' => array('*live*')

));
```

Answer (score 4):

This is how I do set my environment:

Create a `.environment` file in the root of your application and define your environment and add your sensitive information to it:

```
<?php

return array(

     'APPLICATION_ENV' => 'development', /// this is where you will set your environment

     'DB_HOST' => 'localhost',
     'DB_DATABASE_NAME' => 'laraveldatabase',
     'DB_DATABASE_USER' => 'laraveluser',
     'DB_DATABASE_PASSWORD' => '!Bassw0rT',

);
```

Add it to your `.gitignore` file, so you don't risk having your passwords sent to Github or any other of your servers.

Right before `$app->detectEnvironment`, in the file `bootstrap/start.php`, load your `.environment` file to PHP environment:

```
foreach(require __DIR__.'/../.environment' as $key => $value) 
{
    putenv(sprintf('%s=%s', $key, $value));
}
```

And then you just have to use it:

```
$env = $app->detectEnvironment(function () {

    return getenv('APPLICATION_ENV'); // your environment name is in that file!

});
```

And it will work everywhere, so you don't need to have separate dirs for development and production anymore:

```
<?php

return array(

    'connections' => array(

         'postgresql' => array(
              'driver'   => 'pgsql',
              'host'     => getenv('DB_HOST'),
              'database' => getenv('DB_DATABASE_NAME'),
              'username' => getenv('DB_DATABASE_USER'),
              'password' => getenv('DB_DATABASE_PASSWORD'),
              'charset'  => 'utf8',
              'prefix'   => '',
              'schema'   => 'public',
         ),

    ),

);
```

Note that I don't set a fallback:

```
return getenv('APPLICATION_ENV') ?: 'local';
```

Because, if I don't set the file, **I want it to fail** on every server I deploy my app to.

Laravel leverages something similar, you create `.env` files in the root of your application:

```
.env.local.php    // this file will appear only in your local environment, not in production
.env.staging.php  // for staging
.env.php          // for production
```

In those files you add your sensitive information

```
<?php

return array(

    'DB_HOST' => 'localhost',
    'DB_USER' => 'root',
    'DB_PASS' => '1023809182root@pass',

);
```

Create your files separated by environment:

app/config/local/database.php
   app/config/staging/database.php
   app/config/database.php

An then in your files, or anywhere in your application, you can access your sensitive data via $_ENV or getenv():

```
$_ENV['DB_HOST']
$_ENV['DB_USER']
$_ENV['DB_PASS']
```

Example:

```
'postgresql' => [
    'driver'   => 'pgsql',
    'host'     => 'localhost',
    'database' => getenv('DB_HOST'),
    'username' => getenv('DB_USER'),
    'password' => getenv('DB_PASS'),
    'charset'  => 'utf8',
    'prefix'   => '',
    'schema'   => 'public',
],
```

But you still have to set the environment name, which might be a problem in your case.

Don't forget to add those files to your .gitignore file, so you don't risk sending them to your github.

Documentation: http://laravel.com/docs/configuration#protecting-sensitive-configuration

Comment: This is indeed more useful than The Alpha's answer, because `$_SERVER` will not be populated when running PHP scripts from the command line (e.g. artisan).

Answer (score 3):

Actually `$args = isset($_SERVER['argv']) ? $_SERVER['argv'] : null;` will work only if arguments passed to the script when running from the command line. So, in `Laravel`, if you run any `artisan` command then all the arguments passed to that command will be available in the `$_SERVER['argv']` otherwise it'll be always `NULL`.

To check the environment you may use `App::environment()` method or `App::isLocal()` method to check if local and to set different environments you may use:

```
$env = $app->detectEnvironment(array(
    // replace with your machine/host name, gethostname() will return hostname
    'local' => array('your-machine-name')
));
```

Or you may use something like this:

```
$env = $app->detectEnvironment(function(){
    // SheikhHeera-PC is my machine name
    return $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] == 'SheikhHeera-PC' ? 'local':'production';
});
```

Read more on [documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/configuration#environment-configuration).

Comment: I don't want my machine's hostname to be included in version control systems and exposed on sites like GitHub, so the former method is not usable. The latter method will issue `Undefined index: HTTP_HOST` notices when running scripts from the command line, e.g. artisan.