# Access Laravel Config in Bootstrap

Tags: php, laravel, config, environment

I'm trying to use `Config::get('app.url')` to determine my environment; however, it's not yet accessible when being called from `bootstrap/start.php`.

Is there a way that I could fetch that data ahead of time? Basically, what I'm trying to do is this:

```
$env = $app->detectEnvironment(function ()
{
    $domain = strtolower(parse_url(Config::get('app.url'))['host']);
    $serverName = strtolower($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']);

    return preg_match('/'.$domain.'$/', $serverName) ? 'production' : 'local';
});
```

Comment: you are making it way more complicated than it really is. just put the urls in  an array and then use `$env = app()->environment();` to get the env.

Comment: [Check this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24092234/laravel-4-2-says-my-application-is-in-production-how-do-i-turn-this-off/24092409#24092409).

Comment: @itachi I'm trying to set the environment, not get it. Also, it doesn't accept an array of urls, it accepts an array of hostnames. I'd rather not have to update it for each system I sit down and begin programming on. Laravel, internally, uses `gethostname()` and doesn't look at the url.

Comment: @WereWolf Wouldn't that always return local since `gethostname()` would obviously equal itself... :-/

Comment: [Then check this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22673464/laravel-4-detectenvironment-dosent-work/22674102#22674102) but both works because there are explicitly `production is defined`.

Comment: Your first link didn't work, I pushed it to the server and it continued to run in local mode. The second link you just sent me is exactly what I'm trying to avoid. I'm trying to make it so that I don't have to hard-code a hostname in it. I'm already providing the site's domain, it seems counter-productive and a waste of time to have to do both.

Comment: What I've gone ahead and done, though I don't like this approach either, is to `$var = @include('../.env.local.php')` then set `'local' => $var['hostname']`... I still have to configure it for each system, but at least it's in a file I'll already be editing and not wasting my time by having to edit multiple files on each machine.

Comment: let me get this straight. you work on multiple machines so except the one you defined in the environment file, others are regarded as _production_ though they are still _local_. and you want these copies also treated as _local_. right?

Comment: No, I just defined the current (local) machine I'm on in the environment file. I'll have to edit it on each machine I work on, but at least all of the values I have to edit (db, hostname, etc) are centralized in the single file now...

Answer (score 0):

In Laravel 5.1 I use config helper:

```
config('services.loggly.key')
```

And, like someone already said, this is not the way to determine your environment.
 Try `app()->environment()`